# How can I add a small loop of Feynman diagram in this tikz-picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (x);
\vertex[right=1.5cm of x] (y);
\vertex[above left=of x] (a);
\vertex[below left=of x] (b);
\vertex[above right=of y] (c);
\vertex[below right=of y] (d);
\vertex[above right= 0.5cm and 0.75cm of x] (p);

\diagram*{
    (x) --[scalar, bend left] (p),
    (y) --[scalar,  bend right] (p),
    %(x) --[fermion, half left] (y),
    (x) --[scalar, half right] (y),
    (x) --[fermion] (a),
    (x) --[fermion] (b),
    (y) --[fermion] (c),
    (y) --[fermion] (d),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the following diagram:

[image]

What I want to make is to add a small loop on the vertex (p) as

[image]

Comment: Add `p --[out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1cm] p,` to the last of body of `\diagram*` should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Amita Please turn your comment into a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `p --[out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1cm] p` to the last of body of `\diagram*` should resolve the issue.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (x);
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of x] (y);
    \vertex[above left=of x] (a);
    \vertex[below left=of x] (b);
    \vertex[above right=of y] (c);
    \vertex[below right=of y] (d);
    \vertex[above right= 0.5cm and 0.75cm of x] (p);

    \diagram*{
        (x) --[scalar, bend left] (p),
        (y) --[scalar, bend right] (p),
        %(x) --[fermion, half left] (y),
        (x) --[scalar, half right] (y),
        (x) --[fermion] (a),
        (x) --[fermion] (b),
        (y) --[fermion] (c),
        (y) --[fermion] (d),
        p --[red, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=1cm] p,
    };
    \node[below, red] at (p) {(p)};
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
Note that you have already used the `{feynman}` environment within a `{tikzpicture}`, this allows you to access all the commands from `TikZ`. So if you want to remove the cusp in the red line, just do it like in `{tikzpicture}`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (x);
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of x] (y);
    \vertex[above left=of x] (a);
    \vertex[below left=of x] (b);
    \vertex[above right=of y] (c);
    \vertex[below right=of y] (d);
    \vertex[above right= 0.5cm and 0.75cm of x] (p);

    \diagram*{
        (x) --[scalar, bend left] (p),
        (y) --[scalar, bend right] (p),
        %(x) --[fermion, half left] (y),
        (x) --[scalar, half right] (y),
        (x) --[fermion] (a),
        (x) --[fermion] (b),
        (y) --[fermion] (c),
        (y) --[fermion] (d),
    };
    \draw[red] (p) node[fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt] node[below, red] {(p)} arc(-90:270:0.3);
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I found out that replacing p to (p) in your last line does not work. What is the difference of using (p) and p?

Comment: Another thing to ask is that, we have a cusp in the red line. Can't I remove this one? I found out that replacing 135 -> 180 and 45-> 0 do not work.

Comment: @eigenvalue  In my opinion, the `(p)` is the `tikz` grammar for a point used in the environment `tikzpicture`,  whereas `p` is the `tikz-feynman` grammar for a point used in the environment `feynman`.